# How to find out SQL Server CE column's length

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, col

I created a table using SQL Server CE like this:

```
SqlCeCommand createTableCmd = new SqlCeCommand();
createTableCmd.CommandText = "Create table docEntry (id nvarchar (70) not null PRIMARY KEY, "
                + "parent nvarchar(70), "
                + "lmt bigint not null, "
                + "fileName nvarchar(70) not null)";
```

Table name is `docEntry`, and the column width I need to find out is fileName column.

The purpose is to detect if the column width is 70, if yes, I need to expand it to other size, else leave it.

I tried

```
SELECT COL_LENGTH(docEntry, fileName)
```

it caused exception:

> SqlCeException was caught:
>   The column name is not valid. [ Node name (if any) = ,Column name = docEntry ]

I don't know why...

Anyone knows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think you will have to do it the long way:

```
SELECT character_maximum_length
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'docentry'
AND column_name = 'filename'
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>beside providerspecific solution from @HadleyHope there is a solution that works for all Dabases (at least i tried with mssql2005, oracle10, SQlite3 and MsAccess via OleDB. i have no sqlce on my machine to verify):
**DbConnection.GetSchema()**</strike>

This codes works for MsSql.

```
        using (DbConnection con = new SqlConnection())
        {
            con.ConnectionString = ...;
            con.Open();
            DataTable tabeWithSchemaInfo = con.GetSchema("AllColumns");
```

You have to replace `con = new SqlConnection()`
if *"AllColumns"* is not supported by SqlCeConnection call `con.GetSchema()` to get a list of supported properties.

For more info see [GetSchema - DbConnection.GetSchema in ADO.NET 2.0 - Retrieve Databases Tables Columns Views etc. from Database Connection](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/01/15/2734.aspx) and [msdn DbConnection.GetSchema()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.getschema%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: I tried con.GetSchema(), and I got an NotSupportedException. Further search from here shows that it's not supported in SqlCe. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/sqlce/thread/2351c335-e8ac-4534-aa90-66ea59302afa

Comment: Verified: sqlce3.5sp1 with dotnet 3.5sp1 does not correctly handle GetSchema()

Comment: However, SQL Server Compact 4.0 supports GetSchema

Comment: @ErikEJ Have you tried it? SqlCe3.5 also has the api but its simply not implemented ... :-(

Answer (score -1):

Table and column names need to be in quotes:

```
SELECT COL_LENGTH('docEntry', 'fileName')
```

Comment: Fair point. However, I didn't say it did, just saying that the syntax of the function was wrong.